# What Do I Need To Do To Set Up an Akeeba Joomla Restore On AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, joomla

I'm trying to run an Akeeba restore of a Joomla site, restoring it to a site on Amazon Web Services (first time trying a restore to AWS). Using Joomla 3.9 and Akeeba 8.04, PHP 7.3 on the site I took a backup from another source. On the restore site on AWS, I created a database 'joomla'. I then created a user 'joomla@localhost' with password "(password)". I then granted that user all privileges on database "joomla" with " grant all privileges on 'joomla'.* to 'joomla'@'localhost' ".

In the Kickstart restore procedure, I entered "Host: localhost"; "User:joomla@localhost"; "Database: joomla"; "password:(password)". I ran the restore and got an error, "Cannot connect to mysql database".

As far as I know I have a database and a user with all privileges to that database and a proper password on localhost. Yet I'm unable to connect from the Kickstart restore. I'm baffled. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please post all Joomla-related questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  By consistently piling all Joomla questions and all Joomla support in one place in the Stack Exchange Network there is a much better chance of generating better content and providing top-quality advice.

Comment: if you are using RDS you need to check the right IP of your database, and if you are inside a VPC you need your EC2 and RDS at the same network.
You only connect with localhost if you install mysql on your EC2